# how to check if a multidimensional session array is set in php?

Tags: php, php-5.3, php-5.4

In my code i have used the following code to create a multidimensional session array , which i use to store certain details . now i need to check if the sessionis set for certain id , while i run the same function again. 
i have set a session array like this :

```
$_SESSION['table'][$request->id] = array('name'=>$request->name , 'quantity'=>$request->quantity , 'price'=>$price*$request->quantity );
```

now what should i do  later to check if this session with that particular id is set or not?
thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to use the `isset()` function ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: yes , i am a beginner , so please can you give the syntax of using isset with a multidimensional session array

Comment: I'll make a complete answer. Wait a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understand, you want to get a multidimentional array from the user `$_SESSION` or create it if it doesn't exist.

In that case, you can use a code like this :

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['table'][$request->id]))
    $_SESSION['table'][$request->id] = array('name'=>$request->name , 'quantity'=>$request->quantity , 'price'=>$price*$request->quantity );
```

I didn't check the array declaration code. I assume it is correct.